# Deploy an asmx web service to a shared hosting server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to deploy a C# .net webservice to a shared hosting account (arvixe.com).  How can this be done?  I can run the webservice locally, but cannot run it when I upload it to the server via FTP.  I do not have access to IIS on the server.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what error do you get? Is it 404 or 500 internal server error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a wrong server configuration on the domain.  I created a sub-domain (instead of using a folder) and placed the web service within that sub-domain and everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If they've disabled the .asmx handler mappings in IIS then your web service won't run.  You could try a WCF web service, and see if they have that configured.  If you don't *need* an XML SOAP service, you could use an [ASP.NET WebAPI](https://www.asp.net/web-api) REST service, which is more likely to be enabled as it's commonly used to support javascript browser apps.

Or you can run your web service using an .aspx page, although you'll have to handle the request and response XML manually.

Comment: I'm returning Json, not XML  So, no I don't need XML SOAP.  Apparently asp.net Web API will not work either (http://www.dfwcraftbeer.com/dbconnect/)  See the error.  Is there a tutorial on how to run the web service through aspx?

Comment: No. But you just access the HttpContext.Request in page_load read the request, write the response and then call HttpContext.Response.End().  You are responsible for parsing the query string, writing the response headers, writing the response body, etc.

Comment: I just checked with my hosting, and I cannot make the folder an application because it's on a VPS and that isn't allowed.  Does WCF web service require the folder to be an application?

Comment: None of the web service fameworks require their own applications.  You can add WebAPI controllers, .asmx files, WCF .SVC files along with the other files in a single application.  But .asmx and WCF are for SOAP.  If using JSON, either use ASP.NET web API or just handle the HTTP requests and responses yourself.